# Memory limit while index solrfal in TYPO3

Tags: php, solr, typo3

I use TYPO3 7.6 and solr 6.1.3 and solrfal 4.1.0. No I get a PHP memory limit error everytime I've tried to run the solrfal scheduler task. He is still on 57 %. I debugged and deleted the last file he tries to index. But the error was also thrown also with the next file.

I got the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 464255211 bytes) in /var/www/web1/htdocs/leipzig.ihk.de/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/ExtractingQuery.php on line 104
```

on this line file_get_contents() throws the error. The file has only 90KB.  Has anybody an idea?

Comment: If I try to call the function file_get_contents() with the disired file in a separate file and call the file in the browser, everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

I would check to reduce the number of items per run, or increase the memory limit.

Comment: I already increased the limit up to 1GB, set the files to index to 1 and the error was thrown

Answer (score 0):

You need to  Increase `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: I already increased the limit up to 1GB and the error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Got the error. In /typo3conf/ext/solrfal/Classes/Queue/ItemRepository.php on line 154, the first "merged_id" was empty. However this happens. I wrapped the line in a if statement and not it works again

```
if($mergeId['merge_id']) {
     $rows[] = $mergeId['merge_id'];
}
```

Another solution would be to add merge_id > 0 to the where statement.

Answer (score 0):

The previous propose solution does not fix the problem. For me this looks like, that the merge_id is not set in the database and therefore all items will be merged.

By defaut the merge_id has the following format:

'type/fileUid/languageUid/rootPageId'

If there are items in the file index queue without a merge_id your should clear the file index queue and fill it again.